# openssh 7.2 and certificate file

Tags: openssh

I've been using signed ssh keys on Ubuntu 14, which uses openssh 6.6 like this:

`ssh -i path/private_key root@server`

This tries to find file path/private_key-cert.pub and if it finds it and it is a certificate file, it is used to complete the ssh connection and I can ssh to the server. Works perfect!

However this does not work on a server with openssh 7.2. The message I get is

`sign_and_send_pubkey: no private key for certificate "/private_key-cert"`

Seems that there are changes between openssh versions 6.x and 7.2 . How can I make this to work using openssh 7.2?

Thanks